# Expect member declaration error on declared variables in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, instance-variables

I'm a beginner in kotlin and I'm getting errors on my variables when I tried using them. please I need help. Here is my code

```
package com.example.myapplication
import java.util.*
class savedData(hour:Int, Minutes:Int) {
  var calendar= Calendar.getInstance()
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour )
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Minutes )
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0 )
}
```

I get errors when i use the calendar variable in my code above

Comment: What error do you get? Can you be, a little bit more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
class savedData(hour:Int, Minutes:Int) {
     var calendar= Calendar.getInstance().apply{
         this.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour )
         this.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Minutes )
         this.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)
     }
}
```

Within a class body, its properties and methods are declared. The executable code must be inside these methods (or in init {} block, or in some setters/getters, or in scope functions like above), not in the body of the class.

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked for me. I placed my code in a function block and all the errors has been resolved. I didn't know they don't have to be in the body of the class

Answer (score 4):

Your various `calendar.set` calls need to be inside an `init` block:

```
class savedData(hour: Int, minutes: Int) {

    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    init {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    }
}
```

Class-level statements can only be property *declarations*, not code to initialize them.

Another approach would be to use a scoping function like `apply`:

```
class savedData(hour: Int, minutes: Int) {

    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers are basically correct. However, you might also be interested in initializing the property the `lazy` way, so that it won't be initialized as long as nothing needs it:

```kotlin
class savedData(hour:Int, Minutes:Int) {
    var calendar: Calendar by lazy {
        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minutes)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

This is specially useful for creating an instance of a class with resource-intensive init process.